# Iterating over an array of objects using Express and Jade

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm trying to render html using jade, and I want to iterate over an array of objects. For each object, I want to print all of the values on one line in an li.

Here's my backend code using express:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  fs.readFile('./contacts.json', function(err, data){
    if (err) return res.status(400).send(err);
    var contactArr = JSON.parse(data);
    res.render('contacts', {contactArr : contactArr});
  });
});
```

-- contactArr is an array of objects in JSON format like this:

```
[{"name":"Jennifer","email":"jennifer@yahoo.com"},{"name":"Mike","email":"miker@yahoo.com"}]
```

And here is the front end jade code that I'm trying to make work:

```
extends layout

block content
  ul
    each contact in #{contactArr}
      li #{contact[0].name}
```

I've read all about iterating with jade here: http://jade-lang.com/reference/iteration/ , but I can't seem to get the syntax right for iterating over an array of objects to get out all the values.

UPDATE:
I realized that part of the problem was that I was attempt to reference the contactArr incorrectly. The #{ } syntax was unnecessary. Just "contactArr" in the jade code gives me access to the array. However, I am still struggling to figure out how to iterate over the keys in each object in the array.

Answer (score 2):

Just try this code:

```
ul
  each contact in contactArr
    li
      each value, key in contact
        span= key + ': ' + value + ' '
```

In the snippet above, key is the name of the field. So, for your input it should render something like this:

- name: Jennifer email: jennifer@yahoo.com
- name: Mike email: miker@yahoo.com

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be that you are indexing into the individual contact when you don't need to be: `contact[0].name`.

In the Jade `each` loop, you're pulling out each individual object as `contact` already, so you should be able to just use `contact.name`.

Also, the `#{contactArr}` syntax may be causing a problem - within the `each` loop, you should just be able to use `contactArr`.